# Multiple Typescript files in MVC

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc

I started with a Visual Studio template/sample and created a small MVC project. Then I introduced typescript as described in the article:
https://zeroesandones.medium.com/how-to-use-typescript-in-your-asp-net-mvc-project-970676dbf6aa
That worked.
What I want next is to have more than one typescript file and I imagine I have to use export/import. The thing is that I got errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at mainScript.js:1:1)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at controls.js:15:1)
```

What I did that led me to those errors was something like:
-in mainScript.ts

```
import { Ctrls } from "./controls";
let ctrls =new Ctrls();
```

-in controls.ts

```
export class Ctrls { ... }
```

Searching in internet I found many articles but none really helped. I enriched tsconfig.json and package.json. They look now like

-tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noEmitOnError": false,
  "removeComments": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es6", // changed from es5
  "module": "commonjs", // late addition
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // late addition
  "esModuleInterop": true, // late addition
  "lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ], // added to make Promise work
  "outDir": "../ScriptsCustom"
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"include": [
  "*.*"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "wwwroot"
]
```

}

-package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
  "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "type": "module", // late addition
}
```

-_Layout.cshtml

```
<script>var exports = {};</script> // late addition

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scriptsTS")
```

-BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptsTS").Include("~/ScriptsCustom/mainScript.js",
    "~/ScriptsCustom/controls.js"));
```

Now I get

```
mainScript.ts:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined    at mainScript.ts:2:1
```

Which point to ts file but as a matter fact the "require" statement is in the js file which looks like:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const controls_1 = require("./controls");
let ctrls = new controls_1.Ctrls();
```

Many articles say that I have to use something like

```
<script type="module" src=...
```

(I assume in _Layout.cshtml) but as I'm using a bundler, what's the "equivalent"?

I tried various combinations of configurations in tsconfig.json, I tried defining a module in controls.ts. Nothing worked.

I imagine this supposed to be a trivial feature: to have more than one ts file. But how to do that?!